# What camera viewport width and height should I use with orthographic camera

Tags: android, libgdx, orthographic

I am very beginner to game programming and Libgdx. I am really confused what camera viewport size should I use. In some articles i found that they used 480x800 which is same as target device size. In some articles I found the use meters as 5x5 meter.

So which method is better and how (if you can give some benefits).
If I use meter unites for camera viewport then which is first mapped, width or height.

> If i use 5x5 meter for 480x800 pixels device then visible area of world
>
> height = 5 meter = 480px and
> width = 800/480 * 5 = 8.33 meter
> **or**
> width = 5 meter = 800px and
> height = 480/800 * 5 = 3 meter

Is it correct calculation of visible world size and which is used first or second.

*I am confused when they start using meter for size everywhere instead of pixels. like actor size is 1x1 meter even it is only 64x64 px. It is really difficult to estimate position and size for me.*

Please link any good article about camera and camera units.

Comment: I suggest you reading ebook learning libgdx game development by andreas ohelke published by packt publications

Comment: @Maverick I am currently reading that book. But on some point its like he is skipping without explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever dimensions you specify, they'll be mapped to the entire screen by default. If the aspect ratios don't match, the displayed graphics will be stretched. So if you set your camera to a 5x5 coordinate system on a non-square screen without changing the drawing area, it'll be heavily distorted. If you render it in a square desktop window, it'll be fine.

The advantage of using smaller coordinate systems is that it's easier to calculate with, and possibly more meaningful in the context of a game - e.g. you can think of them as meters, as you said. It's useful in cases where the content matters more than the exact positions on the screen - like drawing the game world.

Using larger coordinates which match the resolution of some devices can be more useful when you're drawing UI. You can see how large you should make each image, for example, if you target that resolution. (Scaling can cause distortions.)

But ultimately, it's a matter of preference. Personally, I like smaller coordinate systems more, so I recently coded my level select menu in a 20*12 system. (I did run into problems when rendering a `BitmapFont` though - they were not very well made for scaling like this.) Others might prefer to work with resolution-sized coordinates for gameplay rendering as well. What matters is that you should make sure you're not distorting the graphics too much by badly matching aspect ratios.

Comment: thanks for the details you put + what personally you like. I got why 5x5 meter viewport won't stretch in 480x800 because in book he calculates new `viewport_width = viewport_height / height * width` in `resize()`  . I missed it. thanks.

Comment: @NatwarSingh the important part of the viewport is the aspect ratio (IMHO) as it influences the gameplay. The size itself is only important for your calculations, so you should choose the one which fits best for you. The best would be to use something you have in reality (for example the player being a human -> 2m tall). By doing this you only need to know how big you want the player to be, relative to the screen and you have the viewport size.

Comment: Ok I understand. And once I used meters I have to specify all dimension (origin, position, offset, size etc) in meters. No use of pixel anywhere. Is it correct?.

Comment: @NatwarSingh Yes thats correct. By doing this your gamelogic does not depend on the resolution anymore.

Comment: @NatwarSingh and MPeti: You should also notice the new `Viewport` class, which is available in the nightly builds and will be part of the version 1.0 of libgdx. You can read something about them here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports

Comment: Yeah! viewport is always a problem with different aspect ratio. I will read more about it. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try 136 for Width and 204 for Height